# I need help for below code for loop condition

Tags: shell

```
   #!/bin/bash
    dev="job1"
    test="job1 job2"
    Env="dev test"
    for i in $Env; do
      for j in $i; do
         echo "env:$i"
         echo "job_id: $j"
       done
    done
    
    output:
    -----------
    env: dev
    job_id: dev
    
    actual output i want:
    --------------------
    env: dev
    job_id: job1

    env: test
    job_id: job1
   
    env: test
    job_id: job2
```

I tried the for loop different ways but i didn't get the actual output
how we can loop the lists a i mentioned in the above code

Comment: The variable in your inner `for` loop is wrong. You have `$i`, but it should be `$test`.

Comment: I have multiple environments like below:

   #!/bin/bash
   dev="job1"
    test="job1 job2"
    Env="dev test"
    for i in $Env; do
      for j in $i; do
         echo "env:$i"
         echo "job_id: $j"
       done
    done

Answer (score 2):

You really should use arrays for this sort of thing (keeping in mind that anytime an array is appropriate in a shell script, it's probably a sign that you should use a different language entirely), but to do what you're trying you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev=job1
test="job1 job2"
Env="dev test"

for i in $Env; do
        for j in ${!i}; do
                echo "env:$i"
                echo "job_id: $j"
        done
done
```

If you are using new enough bash that supports associative arrays, you could do something like:

```
declare -A task
task[dev]="job1"
task[test]="job1 job2"

for k in "${!task[@]}"; do
        for v in ${task[$k]}; do
                echo $k: $v
        done
done
```

But this still relies on field splitting to iterate over the values, and bash does not allow you to store an array as a member of an array, so this falls back to the previously mentioned suggestion to use a different language. (One in which arrays are first class citizens rather than ad-hoc baggage tossed in after decades of development.)

Comment: Thanks William Pursell It seems above solution is working as expected.